# Test a custom react hook containing a ref

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-hooks, react-ref

I'm currently trying to test my custom hooks with renderHook from test-library/react-hooks.

I have a hook with a React ref inside :

```
function useSize<T extends HTMLElement> (): [React.Ref<T>, DOMRect | undefined] {

    const [size, setSize] = useState<DOMRect>()
    const ref = useRef<T | null>(null)

    console.log(ref.current, size)

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        setSize(ref?.current?.getBoundingClientRect())
    }, [ref])

    // keep an eye on element size and call a callback when changes occur
    useResizeObserver(ref,(dimensions) => setSize(dimensions.contentRect))

    return [ref, size]
}
```

I'm trying to set the ref value in order to trigger useLayoutEffect and get a value for size.

I tried by writting this test :

```
test('useClick returns the size of given element', () => {
    let div = document.createElement("div")
    document.body.append(div)
    const hook = renderHook(() => useSize())
    act(() => {
        hook.result.current[0] = { current : div }
    })
    hook.rerender(true)
    console.log(hook.result.current[1])
})
```

Unfortunately, it returns undefined.

P.S : I know that I have to mock getBoundingClientRect to get consistent values but first I just want to get a value.

Comment: Does the `useResizeObserver` come from https://github.com/ZeeCoder/use-resize-observer?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I'm using this one : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-hook/resize-observer. I took this one because it seems to use only one global ResizeObserver for all hooks and given elements.

Comment: hey @Iggdrazil. Did you manage to test this? I am just starting to work on a solution for a very similar situation

Comment: hey @Alioshr, the best suitable solution i found is to create a custom react component which uses my hook. It covers most of my use cases

Comment: @Iggdrazil thanks for replying back to me =) As I said, yesterday I was working on a similar thing. I also thought about using a Test component, but I would still face a few similar issues, like lazy loading, performance, and DOM limitation for testing, so this is what I have done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959074/how-test-a-hook-which-depends-on-the-callback-of-resizeobserver-with-testing-lib/71959741#71959741